How to clean a double storage map using primary key?
I have a double storage map.
pub type Schools<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        SchoolId,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        StudentId,
        SchoolData<T>,
    >;

With System.killStorage, I am able to delete single entry from this storage after fetching encoded storage key from chain state using primary and secondary key.
How can I delete all entries from this storage in one go?

I don't recommend do this with extrinsic.
This is no way to do this in one OP, it results in O(n) time complexity.

storage double map key deletion


I suggest writing a migration for this.
If the storage is not that large.

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/storage/migration/fn.clear_storage_prefix.html

If the storage is large.

What is the time complexity of StorageMap::clear()?

